# Deep copy in Python SWIG wrapper of C struct

Tags: python, c, swig

I am using SWIG to generate Python bindings for a C library. The library defines a struct with value semantics. In C++ terminology the struct would be POD - copying it with `memcpy` produces a semantically correct copy.

clib.h:

```
struct s
{
     int i;
};
```

I compile this into a Python module using SWIG. Details on the build process are in an "appendix" of this question.

In C code, we can verify that the assignment operator for variables of struct type have value semantics:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include "clib.h"

int main()
{
    struct s s1;
    s1.i = 100;

    struct s s2 = s1;
    assert(s2.i == 100);

    s2.i = 101;
    assert(s1.i == 100);
}
```

In the Python wrapper, as expected, we instead have reference semantics:

```
import clib

s1 = clib.s()
s1.i = 100

s2 = s1
assert s2.i == 100

s2.i = 101
assert s1.i == 101
```

If our library were written in C++ instead, and `s` had a copy constructor, SWIG would generate one for the Python wrapper too ([reference](http://swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html#Python_nn23)). We could write:

```
s3 = clib.s(s1)
```

but for a C library, this wrapper is not generated:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

We might hope that SWIG generates the appropriate magic methods for `copy.deepcopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy
s4 = deepcopy(s1)
```

but it does not:

```
TypeError: can't pickle SwigPyObject objects
```

I am perplexed. This seems like it should be really simple, but I can find nothing. In [the "SWIG and Python" documentation](http://swig.org/Doc3.0/Python.html), the word "copy" only appears in the previously linked note on C++ copy constructors, and in some low level details about the generated wrapper code. The [closest question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290678/create-a-copy-class-method-for-a-python-object-containing-a-swig-object/57293011#57293011) has a horrifically complicated answer.

---

#### Details to reproduce

Define a trivial SWIG interface file `clib.i`:

```
%module clib

%{
#include "clib.h"
%}

%include "clib.h"
```

Create a Python module using `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

clib = Extension(
    "_clib",
    sources=["clib_wrap.c"],
    extra_compile_args=["-g"],
)

setup(name="clib", version="1.0", ext_modules=[clib])
```

Build the whole thing with a `Makefile`:

```
swig: setup.py clib_wrap.c
    python2 setup.py build_ext --inplace

clib_wrap.c: clib.i
    swig -python clib.i
```

Then, compile/run the Python and C test programs exactly as listed above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a C library can't have constructors/destructors, you can define them after-the-fact for a SWIG wrapper [ref: swig docs 5.5.6](http://www.swig.org/Doc4.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_adding_member_functions).  Note that constructors have to be written carefully:

> There is one subtle difference to a normal C++ constructor implementation though and that is although the constructor declaration is as per a normal C++ constructor, the newly constructed object must be returned as if the constructor declaration had a return value.

test.i:

```
%module test

%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "clib.h"
%}

%include "clib.h"

%extend s {       // add additional methods to the s struct
    s(int i) {    // constructor
        struct s* t = malloc(sizeof(struct s));
        t->i = i;
        return t;
    }
    s(struct s* o) { // copy constructor
        struct s* t = malloc(sizeof(struct s));
        t->i = o->i;
        return t;
    }
    ~s() {           // destructor
        free($self);
    }
}
```

Use case:

```
>>> import test
>>> s1 = test.s(5)
>>> s1.i
5
>>> s2 = test.s(s1)  # copy
>>> s2.i
5
>>> s2.i = 7
>>> s1.i
5
>>> s2.i
7
```

Comment: Follow-up question @mark-tolonen - It wasn't clear from the docs: If I add my own constructor like this, do I also have to add the destructor, even if it's trivial like in your example?

Comment: @japreiss Yes, it’s not trivial in this case. You’d have a memory leak.